# Changing the icon on the "window bar" Mac OS X

Tags: icon, mac

I was wondering how I could change the icon in the "window bar" of my Mac app 
I've also added a picture of the icon I want to change since i believe window bar isn't the correct term.

[image]

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Why was this moved ? This was a question meant for stack overflow... In the original post it had the tag objective-c and also xcode along with mac and mac, and this is something that is manage in Xcode so this is a mistake by the moderators...

Comment: Yes exactly! I can't understand why they did that so I had to open a new post.. -.- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217945/changing-the-icon-on-the-window-bar-mac-os-x-in-xcode

Comment: Trust me, when I got to this question there was no objective-c or xcode tag, but i'll migrate it back if you want.

Comment: Indeed there are no tags. But that doesn't mean it's not related to those topics, it was just mistagged...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`-setRepresentedFilename:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setRepresentedFilename%3a)or the other similar methods. I don't think you can just change the icon to anything, it has to be associated with a file.